# Connection of Rails 3 with Database working under other application

Tags: mysql, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3

i had a doubt ,Suppose there is one desktop application made in .NET which uses SQL server as its DB.All inputs will be provided in this applications and all data will be store in DB.But its Admin webpage is in Rails 3.As per the scenario when user will give some input,it should be displayed in Admin side and admin can edit,delete etc.My doubt is How to connect with that SQL server which stores data and how to create the migration file.

Lets take a example.Suppose user gave the input name,email and password from .NET application side which are stored in SQL server.Admin has to see these which is made in Rails.If the following is my database.yml file and both applications are running in same network(i.e-localhost/any ip) plaese help me how i can configure the migration and set the database.yml file.

## database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_myapp
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_myapp
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_myapp
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost
```

Please help me.

Comment: Well you can't use `mysql` to access `mssql` you would need the `sqlserver-adapter` to do this. Other than that everything should be fairly trivial but your question is unclear as to how we can help.

Comment: @ engineersmnky Let me to explain again.Suppose machine-A has one desktop application which can take only input and save these in SQL server that also present in that machine-A system.Machine-B has one web Admin page and its function is whatever the inputs are provided in that desktop application present in machine-A it should be displayed in this web Admin page.My doubt was how i will connect that database present in Machine-A with the Admin page present in machine-B.

Comment: connecting 2 machines to the same SQL server is trivial at best. If this is your question what have you tried?

Comment: @engineersmnky i am just worried about how to confugure it and creating model in Rails..Can you suggest to start this..or this is same as creating model in rails..?

Comment: this would be the same as just building it in rails. If the db model already exists then just create a model class around it's current configuration and just don't create migrations for it.